# Should simultaneous bulk inserts cause deadlocks, with a PK being an identity column, in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, deadlock

When analyzing a deadlock graph, it looks like the victim is a bulk insert, and the blockers are the same bulk insert. Using a message bus, many subscribers can end up doing a bulk insert at roughly the same time. The deadlock usually happens, but not always.

I think these simultaneous bulk inserts are the reason why the deadlock is occurring. But a colleague mentioned it shouldn't be possible with my setup. The bulk inserts are inserting into the same table. And that table's PK is an identity column. Should it be possible for deadlocks to occur in this scenario? They are done within a transaction.

This is the line of code that does the inserts:

```
await bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(dataTableWithEnumStrings);
```

This is from the deadlock graph. Both the victim and blockers show the same SQL statements.

Victim:
[image]

Blockers:
[image]

SQL:
[image]

Comment: Is their a Foreign Key?

Comment: @yugami There is not. There should be, but there is not at the moment.